# Xamarin.Android - MvxRecyclerView error in release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We upgraded our Xamarin Android project from mvvmcross 4.1.0 to 5.6.3. In debug mode (linker is off) everything works fine, but in release mode (Link all assemblies) we got this error:

> Didn't find class "android.view.MvxRecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.project-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.project-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.project-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file is the newest that I could found in mvvmcross git.

Setup.cs already contains this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new 
List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
{
   typeof(MvxRecyclerView).Assembly
};
```

I tried to add MvxRecyclerView to Proguard.cfg but didn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add this to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file.

```
public void Include(MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.ItemTemplates.MvxDefaultTemplateSelector injector)
{
    injector = new MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.ItemTemplates.MvxDefaultTemplateSelector();
}
```